# Separar números pares e ímpares com dois vetores em C

Tags: c, array, for, while

Tenho o seguinte problema: preciso ler vários números até que o número digitado for 0 ou algum dos vetores esteja totalmente preenchido, no caso o vetor deve possuir no máximo 10 índices, sendo que para cada número digitado deve-se separar os pares dos ímpares em cada vetor respectivamente. Porém quando um dos vetores está preenchido o programa não finaliza, fica repetindo a pergunta do 'for' sucessivamente encerrando apenas quando é digitado o valor 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
int par[10], impar[10], i, num, pares = 0, impares = 0;

do{
    printf("\n Digite um numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    for ( i=0; i < 20; i++){
        if (num % 2 == 0){
            par[i] = num;
            pares ++;
        }
        else if (num % 2 != 0){
            impar[i] = num;
            impares++;
        }
    }
}while((num != 0) && (pares < 10 ) || (impares < 10));
for (i=0; i<10; i++){
    printf("\n Pares: %d", par[i]);
    printf("\n Impares: %d", impar[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: Troque `(pares < 10 ) || (impares < 10)` por `(pares < 10) && (impares < 10)`. Problema resolvido?

Comment: Para evitar confusões com a condição `while` eu fazia um ciclo infinito com `break` lá dentro associado a condições muito simples: `if (num == 0) break;`, `if (pares == 10) break;`

Comment: dentro do próprio for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refiz o programa porque a lógica estava muito confusa.
De quebra melhorei a entrada de dados e coloquei alguns comentários, coisa que infelizmente é negligenciada nas repostas.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int par[10], impar[10], num, pares = 0, impares = 0;
  int i, n_read;

  for (;;)
  {
    printf("*\n");
    printf("* digite um numero: ");

    n_read = scanf(" %d", &num);
    if (n_read < 1)
    {
      printf("* digitacao invalida, ignorando linha digitada\n");
      scanf("%*[^\n]");
      continue;
    }

    if (num == 0)
    {
      // terminando entrada de dados porque leu numero 0
      break;
    }

    if (num & 1)
    {
      impar[impares++] = num;
      if (impares == 10)
      {
        // terminando entrada de dados porque ja' leu 10 impares
        break;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      par[pares++] = num;
      if (pares == 10)
      {
        // terminando entrada de dados porque ja' leu 10 pares
        break;
      }
    }
  } // for

  printf("*\n");

  printf("* total de numeros pares:   %d\n", pares);
  for (i = 0; i < pares; i++)
    printf("* par[%d]=%d\n", i, par[i]);

  printf("* \n");

  printf("* total de numeros impares:   %d\n", impares);
  for (i = 0; i < impares; i++)
    printf("* impar[%d]=%d\n", i, impar[i]);

  printf("*\n");
}
```

Comment: Só uma dúvida, pra que serve a variável n_read?

Comment: o retorno da função "scanf" é o número de variáveis que foi lida com sucesso, no caso 1 porque estamos lendo só 1 variável: num...se você digitar "p", por exemplo, scanf vai retornar 0 em n_read, e o programa vai mostrar a mensagem "digitacao invalida etc", e vai pedir nova digitação

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que utilizar variáveis diferentes para controlar as posições em cada um dos vetores, uma para os pares e outra para os ímpares, você está utilizando uma única variável.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int par[10], impar[10], i, num, pares = 0, impares = 0;
    printf("\n Digite um numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    while ((num != 0) && ((pares < 10 ) && (impares < 10))) {
        if (num % 2 == 0)
            par[pares++] = num;
        else
            impar[impares++] = num;
        printf("\n Digite um numero: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
    }
    printf("%d pares\n", pares);
    for (i=0; i<pares; i++)
        printf("\t%d", par[i]);
    printf("%d ímpares\n", impares);
    for (i=0; i<impares; i++)
        printf("\t%d", impar[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Alterei o código, acho que fiz a forma mais simples para esse problema, da uma olhada:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
int par[10], impar[10], num, i, pares = 0, impares = 0;

do{
    printf("\n Digite um numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

        //Verifica se o numero é zero, se já for sai do loop
        if(num == 0) {
            break;  
        }else{
            if (num % 2 == 0){
                par[pares] = num;
                pares++;
            } else {
                impar[impares] = num;
                impares++;
            }
        }
 //Continua a repetir o do enquanto os arrays nao estão preenchidos       
 }while(pares < 10  && impares < 10);

 printf("\n Pares: ");
 for (i=0; i< pares; i++){
    printf("%d ", par[i]); 
 }

 printf("\n Impares: ");
 for (i=0; i<impares; i++){
    printf("%d", impar[i]);
 }
}
```